# How to check if object is null in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am new to EF and trying to do a small project with it. I added a condition to EF but I am having a problem. 
My condition is all about IN condition like SQL, 
`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1 IN (1,2,3...)`

Here is my EF....

```
var res3 = res2.Where(l => !slitDetail
                        .Any(s => s.BlockId == l.Id 
                               && s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Ara Ürün Depo" 
                               && s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Özel Kesim Depo"));
```

`s.WarehouseDepot` might be NULL sometimes which is normal, but if it is null, this query throws an exception.

How can I check if `s.WarehouseDepot` is null and make it work even if it is null?

Comment: You Can apply This: "var res3 = res2.Where(l => !slitDetail.Any(s => s.BlockId == l.Id && s.WarehouseDepot != null && ( s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Ara Ürün Depo" && s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Özel Kesim Depo")));"

Comment: Are you sure this is EF query? i.e. `res2` and `slitDetail` are `IQueryable`s? NRE is indication for LINQ to Objects query. And there you can check for `null` the same way you check for `null` in any other C# code. Actually you can do that in EF queries too.

Comment: How about adding a `&& s.WarehouseDepot != null` in your `Any` clause?

Comment: Would you still like to check for `s.BlockId == l.Id` in case `s.WarehouseDepot` is `null` ?

Comment: @bit please add your comment as answer. I will mark it

Comment: You accepted an answer, but your question is full of signs that you're not doing this the right way to begin with. Your LINQ statement is LINQ to objects, which is a missed chance, because you can greatly reduce the amount of data fetched from the database. If you want advice how to do this correctly, please show the preceding code that creates `res2` and `slitDetail`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 possiblities if `s.WarehouseDepot == null`

1) You want your `Any` to return `true`, in that case you could use something like

```
var res3 = res2.Where(l => !slitDetail
                        .Any(s => s.BlockId == l.Id
                               && s.WarehouseDepot != null
                                ? (s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Ara Ürün Depo" && s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Özel Kesim Depo") 
                                : true));
```

This would use the `s.WarehouseDepot` only if it has a value otherwise it would return true

2) You want your `Any` to return `false`. In this case you could simply replace the `true` by `false` in the above expression or use something like

```
var res3 = res2.Where(l => !slitDetail
                        .Any(s => s.BlockId == l.Id
                               && s.WarehouseDepot != null
                               && s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Ara Ürün Depo"
                               && s.WarehouseDepot.WarehouseDepotName != "Özel Kesim Depo"));
```

Note that both these outcomes will automatically consider the `s.BlockId == l.Id` condition too.