# Check for null entities in EF statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a statement like this:

```
AssignedCas AssignedCase in caseList.GroupBy(o => o.CaseBatch.CaseBatchName)
                                    .Select(g => g.First()).ToList()
```

But at time `o.CaseBatch.CaseBatchName` can be `null`, in which case the above statement will not execute.

Is there a way in the above statement to check if `CaseBatchName` is not null and only then include it.

Comment: `caseList.Where(o => o.CaseBatch.CaseBatchName != null).GroupBy(...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if object is null in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36883787/how-to-check-if-object-is-null-in-ef)

Answer (score 2):

You should probably just add a where condition in your Linq. Just like this:

```
AssignedCas AssignedCase in caseList.Where(o => o.CaseBatch.CaseBatchName != null)
                                    .GroupBy(o => o.CaseBatch.CaseBatchName)
                                    .Select(g => g.First()).ToList()
```